# Expand the list of folders in the Bookmark added box using Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to expand the list of folders in the **Bookmark added!** box

[image]

when adding bookmark with Google Chrome?

I presume there has to be some registry hack or a special flag somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First i have visited the `chrome://chrome-urls/` and from there i've checked `chrome://sync-internals/` and `chrome://flags/` which are both interesting to "play" around with but i didn't find the required option.

For now i use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get the **Bookmark all tabs** box

[image]

so i can place the bookmark where i want, which is the same as the **Edit bookmark** box

[image]

when you click on the **Choose another folder...**